# Set values on Symfony2 validation with no form

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm coding an API and I'm doing the create method. I'm doing the following without needing a form:

```
$params = array('title' => 'test', 'parent_id' => 781);

// bind data
$place = new Place();
$place->bind($params);

// validate params
$errors = $this->validator->validate($place);
```

I need to check that parent_id is a correct value (its object exist - i know how to do this) and after that, I need to set some values dependent on the parent. So at the end the Place object will have the fields: `title, parent_id, level, country_id` for example.

How would you do this? On the validation? How? If not, how to avoid calling two times the DB to get the parent object?

Answer (score 0):

You should first validate & then set any additional values afterward. Anything that modifies the value does not belong in the validator.

If your using doctrine, it should load the parent object into memory when you first access it, so it won't need to actually query the database again when you access the parent object a second time.